# How to Uniformly distribute Objects based on an attribute in a list?

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Lets say, I have a collection or list of objects {A A B A B  B C C C D D E E D F F F}

The list is populated at random. Now I want it to rearrange the list as follows

{A B C D E F A B C D E F A B C D F}

**One way** to do is create buckets for each element from the existing list, and then go over each bucket sequentially picking and adding the elements in expected list till all buckets last.

Comment: In your bucket approach, is the order of buckets important? Can the result be defined formally? What would the result of the input {A A A A A A B C D E F} be?

Comment: I think result in your case would be :- {A} {A} {A} {A} {A} {A B C D E F}.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, no the order is not important. Just uniform distribution.

Comment: The problem is that the term "uniform distribution" is a bit fuzzy in this context. So what do you expect from the above input. I could imagine basically two options: {A B C D E F A A A A A} or {A B A C A D A E A F A}

Comment: @NicoSchertler, I am expecting order as {A B C D E F A A A A A}.

Answer (score 0):

You can use buckets dynamically. As an example:

Fast version:

While buckets and input sequence not empty:

1. Get next attribute value in sequence X in (A,B, C, D, A, ..... )
2. Check current position in input sequence if it belongs to attribute X, then put it to new sequence and increased position, goto 1
3. If not empty bucket X get from bucket X into new sequence and move to 1
4. Put item from current position into appropriate bucket, increased position, goto 2

Less memory usage version

1. Get next attribute value in sequence X in (A,B, C, D, A, ..... )
2. If not empty bucket X get from bucket X into new sequence and move to 1
3. Check current position in input sequence if it belongs to attribute X, then  put it to new sequence and increased position, goto 1
4. Put item from current position into appropriate bucket, increased position, goto 3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming input would be only A-Z alphabets. So in that case you will be having only 26 possible characters. So just use hashtable to store count for your input character, once input is stored in hash table.
Now just use this function to get the output.

while(there is any item in hash)
{

for(i 1 to 26)
{

print every nonzero count character and decrement count

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Put the objects into a hashmap with their value as key and a counter for the number of occurances (also preserve the insertion order). Then to create the output list, iterate on the keys in the map and append each key value, while decrementing its count. Repeat until the map is exhausted. Here's the code in python:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def arrange(l):

  d=OrderedDict()
  for x in l:
    d[x]=d.setdefault(x, 0)+1

  r=[]
  while len(d)>0:
    for x in d:
      r.append(x)
      d[x]-=1
      if d[x]==0:
        del d[x]

  return r
```